# IBM Worklight v6.0 - Dojo Package conflict

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm installing Worklight 6 into a clean version of Eclipse 4.2.2. Everything appeared to be successful, except upon opening Eclipse there is the followin in the Console Log.

```
[2013-06-22 20:40:01]             The bundle "com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.core_6.0.0.201306140657 [858]" could not be resolved. Reason: Package uses conflict: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jetty.server; bundle-version="[8.0.0,9.0.0)"
[2013-06-22 20:40:01]             The bundle "com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.ui_6.0.0.201306140657 [859]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.core; bundle-version="6.0.0"
```

Comment: I suggest to try installing again on a new Eclipse Jave EE 4.2.2 installation and a new workspace. I've installed 6.0 successfully, started it and created a new project and application with Dojo without seeing these messages. If there is anything else you've done, please edit your question and mention them.

Comment: @IdanAdar starting fresh is not route I can take. Customers often require other plugins like RTC, BIRT, SVN, etc to co-exist. This same problem of co-existence occurred in previous version of the product; Spring Tools Plugin use to to trigger this problem. I need to find which plugins are in conflict.

Comment: Can't help then, as you're not mentioning exactly which other plug-ins you have installed (you did not mention this in your question, either) nor the order in which you've installed them. I have blank Eclipse and it works. So, please check if it works fine with blank Eclipse and work your way from there. If you have something to report back, please do.

Comment: @IdanAdar finding the method to debug was more important that a strait answer. WL debugging is not very well documented, so finding the troubleshooting procedure is more important.

Comment: Adding the -debug flag to eclipse.ini and then restarting found the debug messages in the .log file that lead to the IBM note. RTC plugins appear to be the critical issue and order in which they are installed.

Comment: In retrospect, this is indeed covered in the Worklight 6.0 Information Center under the Known Issues >> Technotes section.

Comment: You installation order is wrong, here is a tutorial to installing Worklight v6 + RTC + MTWW: http://clearblade.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/installing-ibm-worklight-v6-adt-rtc-mtww/ hope this helps.

Comment: After reviewing the IBM technote, I found it worked if you installed WL, then MTWW, finally RTC4. I then removed to Jetty Plugins.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears IBM is aware of issues with plugin co-existence.

Please see issue documented here if you need to Worklight to work with RTC. It appear plugin install order maybe a factor.

[Coexistence Problems: RTC, Worklight Studio and Mobile Test Workbench](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21640931&myns=swgother&mynp=OCSS4HGH&mynp=OCSSZH4A&mync=A)

Comment: Good to know! Please mark this as Answered when possible. Thanks.

Comment: This solutions works if you follow your install order very closely. Along the way I discovered Spring Framework, Spring Grails, and BIRT Suite cannot co-exist with Worklight. Seems to be something in the GEF & EMF plugins they all use.